# How to limit number entries based column/field value

Tags: 2010

I have a list which contains preferred date with three dates like 16, 17 and 18 april 2019. I have to restrict entries per date like for 16th april there should be 50, if user selects 16 again we should through/show message saying the selected date seats are filled please select other dates.

Regards,

Comment: You can write JavaScript code in OOTB new item form in list which will count numbers from list using REST api when user selects particular date. And based on count, you can show error message and restrict form from being submitted.

Comment: Hi Dikesh, thank you so much for reply, would you please post REST api code here, thanks in advance.